# Its showing:- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried changing the object types of the function variables, I tried many things from making them  global to making a new function but still it shows the same error while executing the program!!

Pls debug the code anyone!!

Here's the full code: "https://pastebin.com/DE00hAnt"

Comment: Where did you get the idea of `variable = Widget(...).grid(...)`? A lot of people make that mistake but I don't know what tutorial is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You know when you did this:

```py
w = Entry(P_d, width=25, borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20)
```

Python interpreted it as:

```py
temp = Entry(P_d, width=25, borderwidth=5)
w = temp.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20)
```

So you are storing the result of the `.grid` method (which is aways `None`) in `w` instead of the actual Entry widget. Change it to this:

```py
w = Entry(P_d, width=25, borderwidth=5)
w.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20)
```

Btw your code has a lot of those mistakes. Always split widget creating/widget placement on 2 lines.